# prevent histogram bars from overlapping

Tags: data-visualization, histogram, vega-lite, vega

I am creating a display for 4 similar histograms. This is what I have:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": {
      "one":[8,8,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,7,9,8,8,8,8,9,8,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,7,9,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,7,9,8,8,7,9,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,9,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,9,8,9,8,8,7,8,9,8,8,8,9], 
      "two":[3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
      "three": [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
      "four":[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
    }
  },
  "transform": [{"flatten": ["one", "two", "three", "four"]}, {"fold": ["one", "two", "three", "four"]}],
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "count",
      "stack": null
    },
    "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneoD2AdhvANoAcANJQOxUW2WN1MsUCc7zXNnrlHPQd3q9hQ2gLoSRfLtNaTZQporqqVY0aoaiVAXQogoAdzykAzBQAs12zft2Klh5edPHbh1-cvbbz47e3v5+ge4BER5hkTFRQWHBCUlBBkYAFgBOGMRwJK7hBflFhSXFZaUV5VWVNdV1tQ31TY21qQBmeGgZFi3Nfb0lNv3VQwPDYxPjdXoAvjOGUBkQBFgdGQC2pKBtKNBQGASkIITEC6YgC5nZFyAdXSCzFNt4KGBHJzcmZpdZp7ed3VmqXWEAyAGtcEYAJ4ABxyIAARqCQPMQAcAMZ4MAASwIAHNIQAPSFtbEYV7wEDIdB-KCw+EARzQyyg2JgrMQxFRUJJZIpcCpqEwn3plKZLLZ0GxnJuEDxeKyeOg8MxaAIUBuWBg6IhcAIaBQKFRmJQeG6CFufLeArBGB5C1FAoIeHWuNQKLmQA

The problem is that it is difficult to read where the histogram bars appear on top of each other. I tried adding opacity as well, but it seemed really messy and still difficult to read. I also tried adding a `column` attribute to `encoding`, however with the histograms in separate graphs it is not as easy to get a quick visual comparison of the distributions.

I would like to try placing the bars of the histograms next to each other, similar to this [Matplotlib example](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/matplotlib/how-to-plot-two-histograms-in-one-plot-in-matplotlib/):

[image: multi-histogram with bars next to each other]

How can I accomplish this in Vega Lite?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Grouped Bar Chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_grouped.html). For your data, you could follow that example and do something like this ([editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneoD2AdhvANoAcANJQOxUW2WN1MsUCc7zXNnrlHPQd3q9hQ2gLoSRfLtNaTZQporqqVY0aoaiVAXQogoAdzykAzBQAs12zft2Klh5edPHbh1-cvbbz47e3v5+ge4BER5hkTFRQWHBCUlBBkYAFgBOGMRwJK7hBflFhSXFZaUV5VWVNdV1tQ31TY21qQBmeGgZFi3Nfb0lNv3VQwPDYxPjdXoAvjOGUBkQBFgdGQC2pKBtKNBQGASkIITEC6YgC5nZFyAdXSCzFNt4KGBHJzcmZpdZp7ed3VmqXWEAyAGtcEYAJ4ABxyIAARqCQPMQAcAMZ4MAASwIAHNIQAPSFtbEYV7wEBgjBQz6w+EEPDrXGoG4QQnYnBwAhoFAoVGY9DrQ4IW5kilwEDIdB-KD0ykARzQyyg2JgqsQfywMIg6NxBLgACZDGkMBAwBhuqLVVAUBgAPIZMkEKCUhF4KBQJk3XYI8mO52uyXuz3euaGWmi0nkt6S6WYOlwxXKl1q6DYzVsvF4rJ46DwzFoF03LAwdEQ7m8-mGQV4K3bcWxqk0xMMpkslAo1HGbFgKBpSGljAw+AARkNAsIpINSDJxkHizw1Mpi2W2tBB1dqPZnMhYCZEFxAHVe-2x3MZkA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": {
      "one":[8,8,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,7,9,8,8,8,8,9,8,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,7,9,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,7,9,8,8,7,9,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,9,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,9,8,9,8,8,7,8,9,8,8,8,9], 
      "two":[3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
      "three": [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
      "four":[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {"flatten": ["one", "two", "three", "four"]},
    {"fold": ["one", "two", "three", "four"]}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
    "column": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "spacing": 2,
      "header": {"titleOrient": "bottom", "labelOrient": "bottom"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "count",
      "stack": null
    },
    "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "width": {"step": 12},
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}, "axis": {"domainWidth": 1}}
}
```

[image]